# In the movie Waterworld, what's the new sea level height compared to the actual?

Tags: waterworld

In the movie [Waterworld](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterworld), starring Kevin Costner, what's the new sea level height compared to the actual?

In the opening credits, we see the universal logo and the last portion non flooded is the Andes, western coast of South America, with 4000m high. So the land they are looking for is some place higher than this..

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the end of the movie, they find Dryland, which turns out to be the peak of [Mount Everest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Everest), still above sea level. If I remember correctly, the narrator say it, literally, in the end of the movie. The [alternate version](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114898/alternateversions) indicates it differently:

> For the first airing on ABC which restored footage cut from the film, we see Helen and Enola standing atop the cliff watching the Mariner depart before the film's end credits. As they are standing there they uncover a plaque which tells us that they are at the peak of Mt. Everest.

Finally, [Enola's tattoo](http://hanzismatter.blogspot.ca/2008/10/enola-tattoo-in-waterworld.html) also indicate Mount Everest :

> The characters inside of the circular part is longitude & latitude's actual coordinates.
>
> Latitude = 27° 59' N
>   Longitude = 86° 56' E
>
> Spoiler alert: it is the location of Mount Everest.

According to [Wikipedia's List of highest mountains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_highest_mountains), it peaks at 8,848 meters (29,029 ft) above sea level and the runner up is the [K2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K2) at 8,611 meters (28,251 ft).

**So we could assume the sea raised more than 8,611 meters, but less than 8,848 meters.**

Comment: How do we know it's the peak of Mount Everest? I'm not arguing with you, just wondering...

Comment: Earlier in the movie they dive down to Denver. A water height of 8.6km would put denver at a depth of 7km - much more than seen in the movie.

Comment: I updated it....

Comment: @MartinSchröder the [Andes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andes) peeks at 6,962 meters and where flooded. That still put Denver at a depth around 5km....

Comment: Which just goes to show that, while entertaining, the film doesn't make any ("scientific") sense wrt. sea level. :-)

Comment: I read somewhere that the coordinates on her tattoo were actually scrambled, and didn't have proper indications for which set were longitude and latitude. Though they were supposed to indicate Everest, someone just goofed up.

Comment: There is not enough ice on the planet to raise the sea levels that high. Melting all of the polar ice cap will raise the sea levels 7 to 20 feet depending on where you live. That is catastrophic when tidal forces and storms are factored in. Low lying coastal regions are also several feet underwater. This includes the majority of Earth's major cities...