# How did Waterworld flood?

Tags: waterworld

At the beginning of Waterworld, we learn that the entire world is completely submerged

> *"The future: The polar icecaps have melted, **covering the Earth with
>   water"***

[image]
<sub><sup>Edited opening sequence</sup></sub>

However, according to this rather [fancy video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VbiRNT_gWUQ) from BusinessInsider, if all of the icecaps melted, then sea levels could rise by as much as 216 feet, catastrophically placing many coastal cities and provinces at risk of submersion but hardly *the entire world.*

**Where did the extra water come from to make the Earth into Waterworld? Was this discrepancy ever addressed by the makers of the film?**

Comment: Oh...and someone has gills...let's not forget the *gills*. I think the number usually bandied about is 200ft (not 20) but that still wouldn't do it. - https://filmschoolrejects.com/could-the-earth-become-a-waterworld-e1a9abf0b69f#.3wa1bze4s

Comment: Bad movie physics.

Comment: It's [not clear how much the water levels had risen](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/19277/19561), either, although it seems to be over 8,000 meters.

Comment: Well, Denver is over 500 feet submerged and it's at least 1 mile above sea level. The finale of the film is set at the peak of Mount Everest, some 5 miles up. Either way it's bonkers. **I want to know if they knew**

Comment: @amaranth - I seem to recall reading somewhere that the world had shrunk but I can't find the article/interview anywhere. I might have read it on a reddit board

Comment: @amaranth - Mat's suggestion seems to be far and away the most likely. This film was plagued with dreadful screenwriting.

Comment: It's rather sad. All of the ocean's sponges went extinct. The melting ice caps and the water released from the dead sponges was enough when combined to flood the entire planet except the quaint little tattoo island.

Comment: Apparently there *is* enough water on/in Earth to cover it completely, but it's locked in the mantle. Stephen Baxter's *Flood* and *Ark* are based on this premise. I saw *Waterworld* (and *The Core*) but it was so long ago that I really couldn't say anything about the film's explanation for where the extra water came from. All I remember is melting ice, and that would account for some 200 feet, not 5+ miles, of sea level. Scientifically, *Waterworld* is a mess and I knew it at the time.

Comment: @Hans - I *definitely* recall someone talking about the earth shrinking (something about the tectonic plates settling?) in relation to this film. It's doing my head in that I can't find it.

Comment: @Valorum - A seismologist wrote an article about the Earth shrinking, and declared that it could become a water world at some point (explicitly comparing it to the film). Perhaps that’s what you recall?

Comment: @Valorum This is the article that Baxter references in the afterword in *Flood*. http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v358/n6384/pdf/358295a0.pdf Was the bit about the Earth shrinking in the film itself or was it in reference to the film? I'm not going to waste four dollars on the article, but I might waste 2+ hours on *Waterworld*. An often-wet Jeanne Tripplehorn is not that much of a burden on the eyes...

Comment: @Valorum The original script. http://www.scifiscripts.com/scripts/Waterworld.pdf Non-searchable, but the script's bookended by what the original tattoo was supposed to be. More logical than geographical coordinates (when there is no reference point for any meridian until you've actually found Everest) but the peak extension in the diagram is out of scale. The Andes top out at 6962 metres and Everest at 8848 metres. Maximum possible height over new sea level is 1886 metres. The Moon's diameter is 3476 *kilo*metres. Protrusion on the shadow line would be 1/1843rd of the Moon's diameter at best.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Icy asteroids

According to the tie-in comic series *Waterworld: Children of Leviathan*, the flooding was caused by “icy death” that “rained down from above.”
[image]

Given that this is accompanied by images of asteroids pummeling the Earth, I think we can say that the “icy death” referred to is ice-containing asteroids, and not, say, an unexpected hailstorm. Possibly the heat of impact also caused melting of the polar ice caps. Of course, the number of asteroids needed to raise the sea level significantly would be quite significant, thus releasing a considerable amount of energy—which is fairly consistent with the massive waves also shown. According to Wikipedia, the Antarctic ice sheet, which contains the majority of Earth’s freshwater, would amount to perhaps 58 meters (~200 feet) of sea level rise. Thus the asteroids would need to contain over 100 times as much water as the Antarctic ice sheet, meaning a mass of ice many times larger than the mass of the Chicxulub impactor. So the scientific plausibility of this hypothesis is still questionable (unless the tremendous mass of asteroids somehow was slowed).

Comment: You sir, just won yourself a bounty.

Comment: Good answer, but if that was supposed to be the cause in the movie, I don't think they would have left that out and only mentioned and depicted the ice caps melting.

Comment: @farhangfarhangfar - It probably wasn’t. They probably just got the science even more wrong. This is an interesting retcon or addition to the canon which makes things more plausible, though.

Comment: Basically "getting the science right" in these cases just means burying nonsense a bit deeper. I never liked the English term "science fiction," there's rarely any real science in even the best sci fi . Always preferred the Russian term "fantastika."

Comment: "the heat of impact also caused melting of the polar ice caps"  Just for fun I BotEd this:  after heating the incoming ice to 1750C, there's enough excess heat to dump around 1e**29** Joules of heat into the atmosphere, oceans and crust of the Earth.  (That's around the energy from 10000 years of sunlight!)

Answer (score 0):

There's one other way this is possible--but very very much of a stretch.  If you could wring all the water out of Earth's crust and mantle, there would be just enough to submerge Everest, if added to our current oceans and melted the polar ice caps.  This would not be a natural state for the Earth though.  74% of water on Earth is inside and under the crust.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Is this just a theory of how the Earth _could_ have flooded in that fictional universe though? Or is there evidence to suggest that this is how it _did_ flood? The question specifically asks how it _did_ flood.